How to deep copy xml element content and pass it to java method as string
I have the following xml element:
<notes>
    <isImportant>true</isImportant>
        <content><p>Click on the Link below to direct you the page "&#xa0;Java tutorial"</p>
            <p>&#xa0;<a title="Java tutorial" target="_blank" href="https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial">https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial</a></p></content>
    </notes>

In xslt I need to pass isImportant and content elements content to java method as string.
This is how I am saving those to a variable:
<xsl:variable name="notesIsImportant" select="$inputMetaXml//notes/isImportant"/>
        <xsl:variable name="notesContent">
            <xsl:copy-of select="$input//notes/content"/>
        </xsl:variable>

Within template I am calling java method:
<xsl:value-of select="java:generateNotesJson($customContentInstance,string($notesIsImportant), string($notesContent))"/>

And this is my java class:
public class MetadataHandler {
    public String generateNotesJson(String isImportant, String content) {
        return String.format("{\"IsImportant\": \"%s\", \"Content\": \"%s\"}", isImportant, content);
    }
    
}


The problem is that when I pass content of content element it is just passing text nodes. How can I make sure that I pass all element, attribute and text nodes, basically everything inside the content element as it is?
Above implementation for method call is giving me the following result:
Click on the Link below to direct you the page "&#xa0;Java tutorial" https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial

What I am trying to get:
<p>Click on the Link below to direct you the page "&#xa0;Java tutorial"</p>
            <p>&#xa0;<a title="Java tutorial" target="_blank" href="https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial">https://www.javatpoint.com/java-tutorial</a></p>


In XSLT 3, if you want the string serialisation of a node, use serialize($node). But you don't need Java to write a function to output JSON, you can do that in XSLT 3.

As for creating JSON output directly, you can create XPath 3.1/XDM 3.1 maps/arrays and serialize them directly, with the xsl:output method="json" or (in a local context) with the serialize function setting 'method':'json' in the option parameter.
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all">

  <xsl:output method="json" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="notes">
    <xsl:sequence
      select="map { 'IsImportant' : string(isImportant), 'Content' : serialize(content!node()) } "/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Output as JSON:
{
  "IsImportant": "true",
  "Content": "<p>Click on the Link below to direct you the page \" Java tutorial\"<\/p>\n            <p> <a title=\"Java tutorial\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"https:\/\/www.javatpoint.com\/java-tutorial\">https:\/\/www.javatpoint.com\/java-tutorial<\/a><\/p>"
}

Online fiddle.
